# Downloading video segments from m3u8 links

Tags: python, video, web-scraping, m3u8

I've been trying to learn web scraping using python and am practicing now with download the episodes of a certain baking show (Anna Olson's bake - http://www.foodnetwork.ca/shows/bake-with-anna-olson/episode-guide/) that is streamed from thier site. Looking at firebug's network traffic I found that each episode is downloaded in small segments and starts with an m3u8 file. 
I wrote some code to download the m3u8 files, then open each one as a text file and open and save each segment into an mp4 file. After this is done I've gotten full sized video files (~144MB) but when I open them they don't play even though the player says they have a duration.

Here is the part of the code that opens each text file, downloads the urls from te file and saves them to an mp4 file with the same name

```
import requests
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

folder = r"C:\food\videos\Bake"
files=[f for f in os.listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder,f))]

for episode in files:
    fepisode = open(join(folder,episode), 'r')
    urls =  [link for link in fepisode.readlines() if link.startswith("http:")]
    video_file = open(join(folder,episode.replace("txt","mp4")), "wb")
    for url in urls:
        video_link = requests.get(url)
        if video_link.status_code ==200:
            for chunk in video_link.iter_content(100):
                video_file.write(chunk)
    video_file.close()
```

Here is a sample link to one of the m3u8 files:

http://foodnetwork-vh.akamaihd.net/i/501/859/FOOD_BakeWithAnna_E201b_,medium,highest,high,low,lowest,_16x9.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8?null=

I'm trying to understand what is missing that is required to have the videos play.
Thanks

Comment: segments are not mp4, they are ts.

Comment: I know. I tried at first to save the whole thing as .ts too but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `requests.get(url, stream=True)` ?

Also, try:

```
for chunk in video_link.iter_content(chunk_size=100): 
    if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        video_file.write(chunk)
video_file.close()
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before but didn't find that it made a difference. Maybe because the segments are so small?

Comment: @Amos, I've updated my answer. Please check and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks but it's still putting out the same problem. I'm not sure I understand what the if statment is supposed to catch. If the video_link is being iterated over shouldn't the for loop just end at the end of the iteration and not give an empty chunk?

Comment: @Amos Read the commented line

Comment: I did. I meant to ask what keep-alive chunks are and why they might cause problems?